# $f(x)(1+2x+2x^2+x^3)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}$

Tags: combinatorics

We have $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i$. We know that $f(x)(1+2x+2x^2+x^3)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}$.
We need to find $a_0, a_1, a_2$. 
Also we need to find numbers $r, s, t$ from $a_n=D(3,n)-ra_{n-1}-sa_{n-2}-ta_{n-3}$ for n≥3. 
I already get that $f(x) =\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i \times \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{2k} \times \sum_{j=0}^\infty x^{3j}$.
I am sure that this problem is connected to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2869279/find-no-of-non-negative-integer-solutions-of-a2b3c-200).
Also there is a problem connected with two first ones: To write generating function for calculating number of integer solutions of the equation: $x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 = n$.
Thank you and merry Christmas!

Comment: you can use [Partal Fraction Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)

Answer (score 0):

*For a start.*

Consider that
$$f(x)(1+2x+2x^2+x^3)(1-x)^3=1$$ must hold for any $x$ that is say
$$(1-x-x^2+x^4+x^5-x^6)f(x)=1$$ Replace $f(x)$ by a few terms (since you just want $a_0,a_1,a_2$) and identify the coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Your finding is correct. Indeed:
$$f(x)(1+2x+2x^2+x^3)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} \Rightarrow \\\\
f(x)(1+x)(1+x+x^2)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^3} \Rightarrow \\
f(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^i\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} x^{2j}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{3k} \Rightarrow\\
i+2j+3k=n, \ \ \ i,j,k,n\ge 0.$$
So, if you need to find a few terms:
$$\begin{align}n&=0\Rightarrow (0,0,0) \Rightarrow a_0=1;\\
n&=1 \Rightarrow (1,0,0) \Rightarrow a_1=1;\\
n&=2 \Rightarrow (2,0,0), (0,1,0) \Rightarrow a_2=2;\\
n&=3 \Rightarrow (3,0,0), (1,1,0), (0,0,1) \Rightarrow a_3=3.\end{align}$$
Wolfram [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B(1-x)(1-x%5E2)(1-x%5E3)%7D).

For more, you can see [here](https://oeis.org/A001399).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Could I have one more minute of your attention for explaining how can i get to  $a_n=D(3,n)-ra_{n-1}-sa_{n-2}-ta_{n-3}$ for n≥3?