# How many ways I can make \$5 in 50c, \$1 and \$2 coins?

Tags: combinatorics

With five 50c coins, five \$1 coins, and five \$2 coins.

In how many different way can I make up $5? I need a equation or method to solve this problem rather than guessing with permutations.

Comment: Are you familiar with generating functions?

Comment: nope, but some insight into how to solve the problem in general would be handy too, this is a year 3 kid question i knw

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2869279/find-no-of-non-negative-integer-solutions-of-a2b3c-200?rq=1 might help

Comment: [This](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html) book has a nice recursive algorithm that solves that. You basically take the 2 dollar coin plus all the ways to make 3 dollars with all the coins plus the number of ways to make 5 dollars without the 2 dollar coin. In your case you must also take the extra step of eliminating solutions that violate your constraint on the number of each coin.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what I did was to start with two \$$2$ coins, and decrease the amount of \$$2$ coins.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
$2& $1 & 50c & \text{Okay?} \\ \hline
2 & 1& -& yes\\ \hline
2 & - & 2& yes\\ \hline
1 & 3 & -& yes\\ \hline
1 & 2 & 2& yes\\ \hline
1 & 1 & 4& yes\\ \hline
1 & - & 6& no\\ \hline
- & 5 & -& yes\\ \hline
- & 4 & 2& yes\\ \hline
- & 3 & 4& yes\\ \hline
- & 2 & 6& no\\ \hline
- & 1 & 8& no\\ \hline
- & - & 10& no\\ \hline
\end{array}

I counted 8 ways, because some had more than 5 of the same type of coins, which is why there is an "okay" column in the table.

Comment: I might be wrong but the OP seems to try to know about a method other than counting all the possibilites.

Comment: I guess this is kind of "organised" guessing, but unfortunately I do not know any formulas. kodlu's answer is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Working in cents, find the coefficient of $x^{500}$ in the product
$$
(1+x^{50}+x^{2\times 50}+x^{3\times 50}+x^{4\times 50}+x^{5\times 50})\times \\
(1+x^{100}+x^{2\times 100}+x^{3\times 100}+x^{4\times 100}+x^{5\times 100})\times \\
(1+x^{200}+x^{2\times 200}+x^{3\times 200}+x^{4\times 200}+x^{5\times 200})
$$
and since all your coins are divisible by 50 in denomination, you can divide by 50 in the exponents and look for the coefficient of $x^{10}$.

You can generalize to different quantities (say $m$ two dollar coins) of coins via
$$(1+x^{200}+x^{2\times 200}+\cdots+x^{m\times 200})$$
or unlimited supply of coins via an infinite series where you can usually ignore convergence properties

Comment: See "Concrete Mathematics" by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik, Ch. 7.

Comment: If you divide each exponent by $50$, we want the coefficient of $x^{10}$ since $500 = 50 \cdot 10$.